# where does ionic framework web photo-gallery save photos to?

Tags: ionic-framework

I followed the tutorial at
https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/your-first-app/saving-photos

I managed to save photos via a browser but I can't find the file path in File Explorer.

Does anyone know where it saves photos to ?

`console.log(Directory.Data + "/" + fileName);`

shows **DATA/filename.jpeg** but I wonder where that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Capacitor FS plugin uses IndexedDB for the web implementation. So you can not find file path in file explorer. But you can check them  on indexedDB of the browser.

The Data directory On iOS it will use the Documents directory. On Android it's the directory holding application files. Files will be deleted when the application is uninstalled.

reference: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/filesystem#directory

AFAIK, in android the path should be `/Android/data/<packageName>`.  But I am not sure about IOS.